# Vim: Changing viewports quickly in normal mode

Tags: vim, navigation

I use viewports extensively in vim, I'm forever splitting files into new viewports etc. I typically navigate around the viewports using <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> and a movement key, ie: `hjkl`.

Since there is a normal mode command for switching tabs quickly, `gt`, `gT` and `^gt`, I was wondering if there is a normal mode equivalent without the modifier. If not, what would a good mapping be? `gv` and `gw` are both taken already.

Comment: Why not remap `gh` that is used for select mode (that's equal to saying “never used”)?

Comment: Once upon a time I used [submode](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2467) to create a mode for these motions.  It worked quite well but I decided not to keep it around.  I no longer have the code for it but submode made it very easy to do.  May be worth looking at.

Answer (score 6):

For switching viewports quickly, I use the following:

```
noremap <C-J> <C-W>j<CR>
noremap <C-K> <C-W>k<CR>
noremap <C-H> <C-W>h<CR>
noremap <C-L> <C-W>l<CR>
```

Comment: mmm, it's one less keypress but it's still using a modifier.

Comment: @JoshuaHogendorn - True. I find it convenient because in normal mode my right hand is normally already on the movement keys (h,j,k,l).

Comment: Ah, normally I use a total of four key presses to do switching using the built-in key bindings. First `control`, then `w`, release, again `control`, then the `movement` character. This shortens it down to two presses and removes the time to release in between. Multiple switches only need a release of the movement key and not `control` so subsequent movements are a single key press. Of course it really comes down to a matter of personal preference. :)

Comment: Actually I think you meant `noremap <C-J> <C-W>j` (and so on) without the `<CR>`. Otherwise you'll always go down one line when moving around which may be unwanted

Answer (score 1):

I have the following mappings:

```
map <tab> <c-w>
map <tab><tab> <c-w><c-w>
```

so I can move quickly between windows with `<tab>j`, `<tab>k`, etc... 
Note that this also make easier to use all the other `<c-w>` mappings like `<c-w>t` to go to the first window or `<c-w>b` to go to the last window.
These just become `<tab>t` and `<tab>b`.

Before using these mappings I was using

```
map ,w <c-w>
```

so again you would use this followed by a letter to move around the windows.

If you just want to stick to left, right, up and down then you can directly 
use something like

```
map ,l <c-w>l
```

and so on.

Comment: Hmmm, surprisingly convenient. Not really a direct answer to the question of mapping directly to a normal mode grammatical command, but a good stopgap in the meantime.